# Topological proof of Nested interval theorem

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a Hausdorff space and $\{K_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of nonempty compact subsets of $X$.

How do I show that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}K_n\neq \emptyset$ ?

I also want to use the fact that any compact subset of Hausdorff space is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For $n>0$ let $U_n=X\setminus K_n$. Show that if $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n=\varnothing$, then $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $K_0$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: So $U_n$ is an open set, right? Now, why is it an open cover of specifically $K_0$? Can it be the open cover of other subset?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: **Each** $U_n$ is an open set. Since $K_0\supseteq K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq\ldots$, any open cover of $K_0$ is obviously also an open cover of $K_n$ for every $n$, but this is of absolutely no importance. To show that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $K_0$, use the hypothesis that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n=\varnothing$; it’s a simple exercise in De Morgan’s laws.

Comment: okay, I understand that part, and what do I need to show that $U_n$ does not have a finite subcover?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: If $\mathscr{U}_0$ is a finite subfamily of $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, let $m$ be the largest integer such that $U_m\in\mathscr{U}_0$. Show that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0=U_m$. Then explain why $K_0\nsubseteq U_m$. HINT: What is $K_0\setminus U_m$?

Comment: I finished the proof, but was not so sure if i did it right on the part $\bigcup \mathscr{U}_0=U_m$. If I suppose that $x\in \bigcup \mathscr{U}_0$, how do I conclude that $x\in U_m$, is it because that m is the largest integer?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: You know that $K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq\ldots\supseteq K_m$. What does that tell you about $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_m$?

Comment: Of course! Jeez, I wrote it out earlier but did not see it. Thank you!

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: :-) You’re welcome!